# Runtime Error creating IE Object using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'd like to get data from a website.
It runs the first time when I click on my created Sync button.
For the next click, it shows the error as below.

[image: Error Image]

It got stuck at `CreateObject`, my code as below.

```vb
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") // Error here on second run/click

IE.Visible = True
IE.Silent = True
IE.Navigate2 URL

Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 'Wait 2 second, then check again.
Loop
  
'Do my logic here
    
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

I tried this but issue is same.

```vb
Set IE = New InternetExplorer // Error here on second run/click
```

or

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium // Error here on second run/click
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick google of the problem suggests you need to kill off any IE processes. In case you didn't come across it in your initial research, I have summarised below. It's a 'sledgehammer to crack a nut' and I've no idea why this would be required but you might want to try it to see if it works for you.

Add the following line before your code that starts a new Object:

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe taskkill /F /IM /c iexplore.exe")
```